# Specifying resource models using XML Schema

Tags: rest, xsd, hateoas

I need to formally specify a resource model for RESTful web services and I'm considering XML Schema as a specification language.  Ideally, this resource model would promote HATEOAS style client development.  Some questions:

1) Is XML Schema the best option to formally specify web resources?
2) Should each resource be identified as a custom media type?
3) Is it possible to define the set of link relations for a resource as part of its schema specification?

Thanks,
Cameron.

Answer (score 0):

We are using this

http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can define using XML Schema but you no need to re-invent the wheel. [WADL](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) is the one you are looking for. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language)

> The Web Application Description Language (WADL) is a machine-readable
>   XML description of HTTP-based web applications (typically REST web
>   services).[1](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) WADL models the resources provided by a service and the
>   relationships between them.[1](http://www.w3.org/Submission/wadl/) WADL is intended to simplify the reuse
>   of web services that are based on the existing HTTP architecture of
>   the Web.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language) It is platform and language independent and aims to
>   promote reuse of applications beyond the basic use in a web browser.

[Do you need WADL?](http://bitworking.org/news/193/Do-we-need-WADL)

Comment: Hi Pangea, Yes, I am planning on specifying web services using WADL.  However, my understanding is that WADL does not prescribe how resources are specified.  One common way to specify resources in WADL is to refer to (or inline) XML Schemas.

Comment: Why are you recommending WADL and in the same post, linking to a blog post that precisely describes, why WADL is certainly not a good idea for RESTful services?